# Only the first digit of my data gets put in an array

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, text-files

```
import numpy as np
import asciidata

def leesdata():
    RA = []
    Dec = []
    data = asciidata.open('S0-2.txt')
    for i in data[1]:
        RA.append(float(i))
    for i in data[2]:
         Dec.append(float(i))
    return RA, Dec

RA, Dec = leesdata()
print RA, Dec
```

When I run this I get this:

```
[-0.04] [0.15, 0.138, 0.124, 0.098, 0.088, 0.078, 0.05, 0.041, 0.02,
 0.01, -0.017, -0.004, 0.011, 0.072, 0.079, 0.085]
```

So only the first number of my data gets put in the array RA, but Dec works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the file I'm trying to open

http://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~snellen/PS/S2_pos.dat

Comment: Can you please add your test file so we can replicate your problem? And also correct indentation would be nice.

Comment: Can't you just read the file? I'll post some example code as an example.

Comment: The paramter is pointless if you aren't going to use it, replace `S0-2.txt` from `leesdata` with `S` otherwise you can never open a different file

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd use a combination of open and read for this. Here's how I'd read in a file:

```
f = open('S0-2.txt', 'r+')
RA = []
DEC=[]
for line in f:
    if ( not(line.startswith('#')) ):
        RA.append( line.split()[1] )
        DEC.append( line.split()[2])

print RA

print DEC
```

Comment: When I use your code I get an IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was due to the header on your file, the above should work

Comment: No problem, it would be great if you could accept my answer and +1 this, I'm trying to build up some rep.